# Placing elements in the Center of a div

Tags: html, css

This might be silly question however I cant get my head around it. How to put elements(social media icons) in the center, horizontally, in such a way that they don't break,even if the window is resized ?
Here is a markup:

```
<div class="mob_social">
<p1>Your friends might want to fix their iPhones.</p1>
<div class="mob_icon">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/">
                    <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/facebook1.png" alt=" the three sayings like a slogan regenerate, refresh and renew" title="regenerate, renew and refresh">

                </a>
        </li>
<li><a href="https://www.instagram.com">
                    <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/googleplus.png" alt=" the three sayings like a slogan regenerate, refresh and renew" title="regenerate, renew and refresh">

                </a>
        </li>
 <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com">
                    <img src="http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/twitter1.png" alt=" the three sayings like a slogan regenerate, refresh and renew" title="regenerate, renew and refresh">

                </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I always get confused and hesitate to ask this question. I just want to know how it can be done. Here is a fiddle I created with the icons. Currently the icons are vertical however how to place them horizontally in the center of the page:

http://jsfiddle.net/msLuzrye/

Comment: Set `li { display:inline-block; }` to center them horizontally. If you don't want them to break when minimizing the window I think you will have to set a width for  `.mob_social` like `.mob_social { width:200px; margin:0 auto; }`

Comment: Why the JavaScript and jQuery tags?

Comment: @j08691 lets just attach a bunch of tags and get maximum exposure rather than directing the question to the people who would most likely know the answer...

Comment: Apologies for that, actually it was recommended and I thought, "hey why not !" , and you are corret it does not make sense as it is a CSS question and there are javascript tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle with horizontally aligned icons and the whole container div centered on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/msLuzrye/5/

two main tricks here. I'm displaying your `<li>` elements as `inline-block` and then using CSS transforms to center your parent `<div>` vertically. For the parent div, positioning `absolute` and the `top: 50%` puts the top of the div half way down the page. The CSS transform is relative to the element itself, so `transform: translateY(-50%)` pulls your element back up the page half of its own height resulting in a perfect vertical centering.

You can check browser support for CSS transforms [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

Comment: And as always, I would suggest using this link as a refer for all of your alignment needs:
http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block` to your list:

```
li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msLuzrye/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is the most important part to get the icon into a place. Will keep that in mind !!!